# Rails - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=27):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord, model-view-controller

I'm building an Event app using Rails and have comments as a nested resource. I'm trying to implement an Edit function using Ajax/in-line editing but my Edit link isn't working.
I'm not getting an error up on screen but I am getting above error from my development log. The comment 'id' = 27 relates to the event_id not the comment id. How do I rectify this? 
Here's the relevant code -

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def create

        @comment = @event.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @event
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


    # GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit

        respond_to do |f|
            f.js 
            f.html 
        end
    end

    def show
    end



    def update 
        if @comment.update(comment_params)
            redirect_to @event, notice: "Comment was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end



    def destroy

        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end

    private

    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_event
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end


    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
    end


end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
  <div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <div id="<%=dom_id(comment)%>" class="comment">  
      <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
      <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>

  </div>

      <% if user_signed_in?  %>
      <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_comment_path(@event, @comment.event), id: "comment", remote: true %></p>
      <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [@comment.event, comment],
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button",
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#comment').append('<%= j render 'form' %>');
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I've checked the routes and they're all as they should be.I can't check whether the in-line editing will work unless I fix this first.

Comment: why this? `edit_event_comment_path(@event, @comment.event)`? both are passing events, do `edit_event_comment_path(@event, @comment)`

Comment: Then I get 'missing required keys [:id] ' error on the page.

Comment: is it `@comment` or just `comment`? I see it as `comment` in your view, use it

Comment: It does it for both/either which is bizarre.

Comment: where is the `form` you are rendering through js?

Comment: Just added it..

Comment: where are `@comment` and `@event` initialized?

Comment: What do you mean? All the relevant code is attached above.

Comment: my bad, `callbacks` i see, as i can see, my first comment should work anyway. Try this though `edit_event_comment_path([@event, @comment])`

Comment: Same thing, no error's on the page now but development log still trying to point to event_id and edit link not working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have two before actions, set_event and then set_comment.

If you've set both of these to look for params[:id], then it means they will obviously both be using the same value for a search. You will need to change one of them, let us say set_event, to something like:

```
def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end
```

You will also have to change your routes to account for the new id. If you are using your standard resource routes:

```
resources :events, param: event_id do
  resources :comments
end
```

This will give you routes such as:

```
localhost:3000/events/:event_id/comments/:id
```

Which you can then use to find your events and comments.